# How can my node.js server print something out automatically?

Tags: node.js, printing, serial-port

I have a server that is going to automatically pull down data I need to be printed. How can I automate the actual printing of the data when the event is fired?

I've worked a little bit with node-serialport interfacing with an Arduino but never something like a printer.

Answer (score 1):

You could look over the Google Cloud Print API
http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/cloudprint/docs/sendJobs.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a node module that binds printers on POSIX and Windows. Here's the link: https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer